# Java String.equals() algorithm

Tags: java, string, algorithm

anyone know what is the algorithm using in `String.equals()` in Java ? How does Java compare two words?

Comment: Have you looked at the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/String.java#String.equals%28java.lang.Object%29)?

Comment: or java doc ?http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple Function from [String](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html)

```
    /**
 * Compares this string to the specified object.  The result is {@code
 * true} if and only if the argument is not {@code null} and is a {@code
 * String} object that represents the same sequence of characters as this
 * object.
 *
 * @param  anObject
 *         The object to compare this {@code String} against
 *
 * @return  {@code true} if the given object represents a {@code String}
 *          equivalent to this string, {@code false} otherwise
 *
 * @see  #compareTo(String)
 * @see  #equalsIgnoreCase(String)
 */
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
    if (this == anObject) {
        return true;
    }
    if (anObject instanceof String) {
        String anotherString = (String) anObject;
        int n = value.length;
        if (n == anotherString.value.length) {
            char v1[] = value;
            char v2[] = anotherString.value;
            int i = 0;
            while (n-- != 0) {
                if (v1[i] != v2[i])
                        return false;
                i++;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: So Java just use this to compare between two string? No any algorithm is used?

Comment: Um... you're looking at the algorithm right now, @Dummy1234.

Comment: So, what is the name of this algorithm ?

Comment: @Dummy1234, don't be disturbed overly if the algorithm doesn't have a name.

Comment: @Dummy1234 For your convenience, you can name it as Dummys Algorithm ;-}

Comment: The name is the `String.equals` algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

You can see all implementation of java classes in JDK.

Just go to your JDK_HOME where you find '**src.zip**' which contains source code for all java classes where you can easily find implementation of String class.